# Interceptor doesn't get called with spring security permit all access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spirng boot and security 3.2.3. I registered an interceptor to handle specific path in this way:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAdminInterceptor jwtTokenAdminInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        log.info("Start registering custom interceptors...");
        registry.addInterceptor(jwtTokenAdminInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/admin/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/admin/employee/login");
    }
}
```

And I configged the spring security in this way:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean

    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*")); // Allow all origins for development
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

It's in development so I give access to all source. Currently, I can see the "Start registering custom interceptors..." log when the application is started. But unfortunately, the interceptor, which is the `JwtTokenAdminInterceptor` never works. The implementation of the interceptor is currently very simple:

```java
@Component
public class JwtTokenAdminInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (!(handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) {
            return true;
        }

        log.info("Interceptor is called.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I see in some tutorials, they `@Override` the `preHandle` but mine doesn't allow me to and gives me "Method does not override method from its superclass" error.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: can you confirm whether you override HandlerInterceptor interface by providing the package name  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

Comment: If the `@Override` doesn't work and gives you that error, you are using the wrong method name or arguments. That being said I would also say an interceptor is the wrong place to handle JWT, that should be in a filter which is part of the security filter chain.

Comment: @ManojKrishna Yes. My imports are ```
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; ```

Answer (score 0):

I finally notice that `HandlerInterceptor` is using `jakarta.servlet.http` instead of `javax.servlet.http`. There was a transaction from Javax to Jakarta. I hope this could help.